# How to turn a group ring $R(G)$ into a ring?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, abelian-groups, group-rings

Let $R(G)$ be a given abelian group ring. Any abelian group ring is isomorphic to an abelian ring.
I know how to express (isomorphism) some group rings as a ring. But I wonder if there is a general method for finding how to write a given abelian group ring as an abelian ring ?
I mean a method that is not trial and error. Also it must be efficient and always halt to the correct answer.

Comment: Are you saying something like $R[C_n]\cong R[x]/(x^n-1)$ and trying to see if there is a general way to describe the group ring of an abelian group in general?

Comment: Yes but even more than that.
As an example $R[C_4]\cong R[x]/(x^4-1)$ is solved by letting $x=(-1,i)$. So I want a way to know what $x$ is too. Not just the $\cong R[x]/(x^n-1)$ part. But also the $x=...$ part.

Comment: What's an «abelian group ring»? The group ring of an abelian group? There is some usefulness in saying abelian for groups and commutative for rings... Also, it would not hurt if you made explicit what you mean by group ring, as there are at least two different meanings for that term.

Comment: I ONLY know one meaning of group ring !!??

Comment: I have no idea at all what you are asking. What do you mean by "turning a group ring into a ring"? It's a ring already.

Comment: By Wedderburn's Theorem, the complex group algebra of a finite abelian group of order $n$ is isomorphic as an algebra to the direct sum of $n$ copies of ${\mathbb C}$. Are you looking for an explicit isomorphism there? (I don't know how to do that I'm afraid - you would need to ask an expert in representation theory.)

Comment: I too am curious about what is actually meant by this question.

Comment: Yes I believe Im looking for the exaxt isomorphisms, isnt my comment made here clear ?

Comment: @mick: I've posted a partial answer based on my understanding of the question after reading all comments, especially Derek Holt's, but I think the question would still benefit from some editing. What about the title "How to describe the ring structure of a group ring of an abelian group?"

Comment: Too the critics, group ring is a math term. Nothing unclear about it. I considered to rewrite the OP, but all is said correct. Sorry to be arrogant but that is frustrating.
Maybe cyclic group rings is a special case easier to answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the case of rational group algebras, one can use the package [Wedderga](http://alexk.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/wedderga/) for the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) system, for example:

```
gap> LoadPackage("wedderga");
...
gap> QG:=GroupRing(Rationals,CyclicGroup(4));
<algebra-with-one over Rationals, with 2 generators>
gap> WedderburnDecomposition(QG);
[ Rationals, GaussianRationals, Rationals ]
...
gap> QG:=GroupRing(Rationals,ElementaryAbelianGroup(4));
<algebra-with-one over Rationals, with 2 generators>
gap> WedderburnDecomposition(QG);
[ Rationals, Rationals, Rationals, Rationals ]
...
gap> QG:=GroupRing(Rationals,DirectProduct(CyclicGroup(4),CyclicGroup(32)));
<algebra-with-one over Rationals, with 7 generators>
gap> WedderburnDecomposition(QG);
[ Rationals, GaussianRationals, Rationals, CF(32), CF(16), CF(8), 
  GaussianRationals, Rationals, CF(32), CF(16), CF(8), GaussianRationals,
  GaussianRationals, CF(32), CF(16), CF(8), GaussianRationals, 
  Rationals, CF(32), CF(16), CF(8), GaussianRationals ]
```

The function `WedderburnDecomposition` returns a list of simple algebras whose direct sum is isomorphic to the group algebra given as input.